# How can I take each character from a string along with its position in Java?

Tags: java, string, position, character

ie. My string is "pqrstuw". How can I get " t" with its postion 4. I want to edit each character and change its postion. Is it possible in Java?

Comment: Yes, it is. Give five minutes, I will make example for you.

Comment: `How can I get " t" with its postion 4` - check out the String API for a method you can use. `I want to edit each character and change its postion.` - check out the StringBuilder class.

Comment: `I want to edit each character and change its postion. Is it possible in Java?` ... it will be better if you provide some examples

Comment: I think you can convert the String => character array (by using String's toCharArray() method), edit as you wish and convert character array back to String (by using String' constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and call `String#charAt()`... this is the character at the zero base-index, always having in mind that Strings objects are inmutable.

Answer (score 0):

All we know that `String`  is a Immutable (final) class defined in JDK. So, It is not recommend and very cozy to manipulate a String in Java.

There are two simple ways to manipulate the string in Java.

> 1. Using StringBuilder  Class.
> 2. Change to char Array  Using `.charArray()` method of `String` Class .

### Using StringBuilder Class

The principal operations on a `StringBuilder` are the `append` and `insert` methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type.

Each effectively converts a given datum to a `string` and then **appends or inserts** the characters of that string to the `string builder`.

The append method always adds these characters at the end of the builder; the insert method adds the characters at a specified point.

Now Here is the code

```
String str = "pqrstuw";
StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(str);
strBuild.indexOf("t"); //return first index where t is found which is 4.
strBuild.lastIndexOf("t"); //return last index where t is found which is 4.
strBuild.getCharAt(4); // you will get t.
strBuild.setCharAt(4,'v');
strBuild.append("v"); append element at last.
```

there are various more overloaded method there is `StringBuilder` Class. You can do it in Your Way of Manipulation.

### Using char Array

```
String str = "pqrstuw";
char [] arr_str = str.toCharArray(); //it convert your String into a char Array.
 //after manipulation you can change your char Array to String as like
str = arr_str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a string variable 'word' contains what you need. Use the code below to print the various characters in it. Also add the headerfile needed ( java.lang.String; )

```
int size =  word.length();               // Get length of string

for(int i =0 ; i<size ; i++) {  
    System.out.println(word.charAt(i));  // To print i+1'th letter
}
```

string_name.charAt(i) will give you the 'i+1'th character in your string. In your case, if word = "pqrstuvw", then word.charAt(3) will give you 't' which is the 4th character of the string.As for your second question, you need to be a little more clear on what kind of position changing you want to do in your question.

The following is an answer from another similar question: "Replacing a character at a specific position in the string.

Strings are immutable in Java. You can't change them.

You need to create a new string with the character replaced.

```
 String myName = "domanokz";
 String newName = myName.substring(0,4)+'x'+myName.substring(5);
```

Or you can use a StringBuilder:

```
 StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("domanokz");
 myName.setCharAt(4, 'x');

 System.out.println(myName);
```